# How do I get the depth data of objects closer than 800mm?

Tags: unity, kinect, zigfu

I'm trying to scan the layout of blocks on a table. My Kinect can be at most 1m away from the surface and I need to stack those blocks higher than 20 cm. I'm using Zigfu.

Using the kinect 1 I have to deactivate the near mode, which results in every depth data smaller than 800 (0.8m) to be defaulted to 0.

Is there a workaround? I know, that objects this close aren't detected correctly. I just need about 10 cm more and I am willing to sacrifice precision for it.

Comment: Is this really a problem with just your Kinect, and not a problem for anyone who uses whatever you are building?  If so, there are after-market lenses that can accommodate using the device in less than the recommended space.

Comment: Its supposed to be a game. So it would be preferable, if you dont need extra Hardware. But I think I will give it a try. thx